# email header without recieved or source ip informations

Tags: email, spam

today i received and email that has no received or anything just these 5 lines
this email has no source or received syntax all it has 4 lines

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Subject: values
From: values
To: values
```

how is this even possible? it makes no sense where is the email originating ip or server
i tried many times to mimic this email but keep getting smtp sources on header is this not normal smtp or it some sort of witchcraft

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious causes of "No Received: headers":

1. email delivered directly to recipient's mailbox
   e.g by program running with recipient's OS account privileges
2. IMAP/POP3 server tweak for (all users) announcements
3. local SMTP/MTA configuration for deliveries without `Received:` header.

Some mail provides offer free of charge email accounts for right to deliver "pre-accepted advertisents".
Lack of `Received:` headers makes them unfit for spam reporting e.g. via spamcop.net.

Comment: 0


i understand what are you saying but let me give you an example on my vodafone.de email provider i get spam every day with spoofing

do you think these spammers have my user and password and they are directly putting things in my inbox?

Answer (score 0):

i understand what are you saying but let me give you an example on my vodafone.de email provider i get spam every day with spoofing

do you think these spammers have my user and password and they are directly putting things in my inbox?

```
'Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="===============2994445607785670320=="
MIME-Version: 1.0
Subject: Sie haben einen VW POLO GTI 2020 gewonnen
From: Volkswagen Deutschland <vwPolo2020@Volkswagen.de>
To: saarking@arcor.de'
```